# Performance Hit by deploying signed assembly outside of GAC

Tags: c#, performance, .net-assembly, signing

As I understand if a signed assembly is deployed in GAC then before deploying the assembly into the GAC the .NET runtime ensures that the assembly is legit and all its signatures and metadata information is valid. On subsequent use when this assembly is loaded into a client application from GAC the .NET runtime skips verifying the hash values of the assembly contents.

However when an unsigned assembly is loaded into a client application from outside of GAC (say a bin folder of the client app) then the .NET runtime computes the hashes of the signed assembly again, calculates the checksums and compares this value with the embedded metadata that was generated as a part of signing the assembly.

My question is how much of a performance impact does this entail? If a signed assembly is deployed outside of GAC then roughly (if possible) how slow it is loaded into the app domain as opposed to if it were installed into GAC.

**Reason for asking**
I am developing an assembly which depends on certain assemblies such as Autofac and log4Net. While I can sign my assembly these other assemblies are not signed and cannot be deployed into GAC.